# How to see remote changes to branches in Git?

Tags: git

There must be something I've overlooked when I learned Git. After all I'm fairly new to it.

My workmate says he's pushed back some changes he made to my commit in our remote repository.
However the git log has no record of this new push.

How can I see what he pushed and thus know what branch to pull?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to `git fetch` his changes first. you can then show them using `git log origin/branch` (branch being very likely `master`)

`git fetch` retrieves all the remote changes, copies them to your local clone and updates the remote-tracking branches (those `origin/…` stuff, see `git branch -a`). to get his changes into your local branch, use either `git pull` or `git merge`

Comment: Alternatively to git log, you can also use the graphical tool gitk (for which you'll want to show all branches: gitk --all), or in console mode: git show-branch -a

Answer (score 5):

When you have the origin fetched like mentioned, you can always

```
git status
```

which will mention your current branch and whether you are ahead/behind the tracking branch (man git branch)

```
git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline HEAD...origin/master
```

is my very very preferred alias for things. I have even created an alias for this (`lr` from left-right) and extended bash_completion for the purpose.

Consider adding a remote for the origin (if you clone from the origin, you'll have one automatically). You can then 'git remote update' to get all latest refs from the remote

Comment: Very good alias, for the reader just don't forget to `git fetch` before ;)