# definition of gitk's "Mark Branch Sides" option

Tags: linux, git, gitk

In gitk, there is an option in the "Edit View" (F4) window called "Mark branch sides".  It seems to correspond to the --left-right option:

```
+set known_view_options {
+    {perm    b    . {}               {mc "Remember this view"}}
+    {args    t50= + {}               {mc "Commits to include (arguments to git log):"}}
+    {all     b    * "--all"          {mc "Use all refs"}}
+    {dorder  b    . {"--date-order" "-d"}      {mc "Strictly sort by date"}}
+    {lright  b    . "--left-right"   {mc "Mark branch sides"}}
```

The only difference I can see is that the commits are marked by triangles instead of circles.  What is this option supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it is linked to the [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)  or [git rev-list](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) --left-right option:

> Mark which side of a symmetric diff a commit is reachable from.
> Commits from the left side are prefixed with `<` and those from the right with `>`

(the `<` and `>` should explain the triangles used in gitk)

From [ProGit book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-1.html):

> A common switch to use with the log command in this case is `--left-right`, which shows you which side of the range each commit is in. This helps make the data more useful:

```
$ git log --left-right master...experiment
< F
< E
> D
> C
```

(It helps for [seeing remote changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322303/how-to-see-remote-changes-to-branches-in-git/5326967#5326967))

---

[Dmitry Avtonomov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88814/dmitry-avtonomov) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324763/definition-of-gitks-mark-branch-sides-option/7324882?noredirect=1#comment131901517_7324882) (eleven years later):

> To make "`Mark branch sides`" make any difference in gitk, you need to specify a range in text field "`Additional arguments to git log`", e.g. like in VonC's example: "`master...experiment`".
>
> There also need to be some commits present only on one of those specified branches.

Comment: Hmm. I'm looking at linux kernel git and I've done a lot of merges, but all the triangles are pointing right.

Comment: 11 years later... to make "Mark branch sides" make any difference in gitk, you need to specify a range in text field "Additional arguments to git log", e.g. like in VonC's example: "master...experiment". There also need to be some commits present only on one of those specified branches.

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.